# Selenium Issue After MacOS Montgomery 12.6 Update

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

Just Updated to MacOS Montgomery 12.6

**Selenium**

```
<selenium.java.version>3.141.59</selenium.java.version>
```

**FirefoxDriver**

```
geckodriver_0.29.1
```

The tests worked fine until i restarted my Mac after the update

Now when running the tests they will fail with the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:27173
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'xxxxxxxx', ip: 'xxxxxxxxxx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_331'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
```

**BUT**
If i do a **MVN CLEAN INSTALL** i can run one test.

If i run another test it will fail and setup

If i do another **MVN CLEAN INSTALL** i can run one test again

**WHAT I HAVE DONE**

1. Clear Caches
2. Reverted FireFox
3. Reverted Intellij IDEA
4. Clear Intellij IDEA cache
5. Rebuilt Project

Everything was working fine before the update (Any Ideas what be helpful)

Thanks

Comment: I would also try updating your geckodriver to [the latest version](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

Comment: It cannot be a driver issue as when running a test with multiple data providers (running more than one test) the first test will work fine but the second test will fail to load the firefox drivers and connect.